# Encryption program - i don't get why it throws these errors

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating an encryption program, in python, with a simple cipher, reverse the string and go 3 letters forward in the alphabet.

```
original = input('Enter a phrase: ')
actual_word = original[::-1]

def mid(s, offset, amount):
    return s[offset:offset+amount]

def encrypt(word):
    for i in len(word):
        newtxt = mid(word, i, 1)
        newtxt = chr(ord(newtxt)+3)
        coded = coded + newtxt
    return coded

encrypted = encrypt(original)
print(encrypted)
input('Press ENTER to exit')
```

However I am getting these errors and I don't understand why I get them:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\MHT\Desktop\Python\Kryptering\Encryption.py", line 14, in <module>
    encrypted = encrypt(original)
  File "C:\Users\MHT\Desktop\Python\Kryptering\Encryption.py", line 8, in encrypt
    for i in len(word):
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: `1` don't write in capital case. `2` You should tag with [tag:python] as well.

Comment: Shorter: `def encrypt(word, shift=3): return ''.join(chr(ord(i)+shift) for i in word)`. You can also use this to 'decrypt' with a negative shift (-3). But note that this is not encryption but obfuscation (at most).

Comment: About the error, `len` returns an int which is not iterable (see the answer below for a solution). Then you'll have to to fix a `UnboundLocalError` exception by defining `coded` - or use the shorter version described in my previous comment.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the for call be

```
for i in range(len(word))
```

?

`len` just returns the length of the word that is a number